# Combining Multiple Area Targets in Vuforia,

Tags: vuforia

So, I am trying combine multiple area targets in Vuforia. I have two area target scans, AT1, and AT2 In order to test the tracking I have placed a cube as a child game object of AT2. However, when I run the app, I can't see the cube. When I place the cube as a child object of AT1, I can see it when I run the app. It turns out that only AT1 is being tracked and not AT2.

I have followed the documentation in Vuforia ( [https://library.vuforia.com/develop-area-targets/multiple-area-targets#:~:text=Combining%20Multiple%20Area%20Targets%20Multiple%20Area%20Targets%20made,a%20single%20AR%20experience%20over%20a%20larger%20area](https://library.vuforia.com/develop-area-targets/multiple-area-targets#:%7E:text=Combining%20Multiple%20Area%20Targets%20Multiple%20Area%20Targets%20made,a%20single%20AR%20experience%20over%20a%20larger%20area). ) for combining multiple area targets, but I still am facing the same problem. Has anyone worked with multiple targets and how did you combine and track them in Vuforia.

Thanks.

Comment: Are both targets active? Does each target work when used alone?

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same solution but sadly looks like some area markers can override or the system can detect the markers in the same place and is an issue, Maybe a solution for you is having a big area marker, but with colliders. But if the 2 area markers overlaps, if those are far away, maybe too you can do that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).